# Applications of the Bose-Hubbard model

Tags: lattice-model, models

the Bose-Hubbard Model is used to describe ultracold bosonic atoms in optical lattices.

Are there any other systems, where this model is used?

Best

Comment: It might be relevant for studying superconductivity (Cooper pairs are 'quasi-bosons').